# T-SQL - ODSOLE Extended Procedure The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long

Tags: json, sql-server, api, http-authentication

I goal is to connect to a webapi and request data.

I am quite sure that I am connected and I am getting data back because the error message indicated that there is to much data to store.
If my @url + @respondsbody is set correctly I should not get more then 2500 characters.

Error:
[image: screenshot of error message]

Does someone see why is failing on me?

```
    DECLARE 
    @object int,
    @hr int,
    @src varchar(8000),
    @desc varchar(8000),
    @authHeader NVARCHAR(4000),
    @contentType NVARCHAR(4000),
    @postData NVARCHAR(2000),
    @responseText NVARCHAR(4000),
    @responseXML NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ret INT,
    @status NVARCHAR(4000),
    @statusText NVARCHAR(4000),
    @token INT,
    @methodName varchar(50) = 'GET',
    @requestBody varchar(8000) = '$select=*&limit=1',
    @UserName nvarchar(100) = 'dummy',
    @Password nvarchar(100) = 'dummy' 
DECLARE 
    @url NVARCHAR(4000) = 'https://restapi.dummy.com/prod/rest/api/v1/01/products';
DECLARE
    @json AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(4000));



SET NOCOUNT ON
IF    @methodName = ''
    BEGIN
        select FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set'
        return
    END

-- Set Authentications
SET @authHeader = 'BASIC 123456789';
SET @contentType = 'application/json';

-- Open a connection
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN  
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT   
            RAISERROR('Error Creating COM Component 0x%x, %s, %s',16,1, @hr, @src, @desc)  
            RETURN  
        END;  

-- make a request
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, @methodName, @url, 'false', @UserName, @Password;
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'Open failed',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed: Authentication',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed: Content-type',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

DECLARE
    @len int
    SET @len = len(@requestBody);

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len;
IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed: Content-Length',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', null, @requestBody
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'Send failed',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

-- Handle responce
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
            SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
                source = @src,
                description = @desc,
                FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed',
                MethodName = @methodName 
            goto destroy 
            return
        END

-- Print response
--PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
--PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Grab the responseText property, and insert the JSON string into a table temporarily. This is very important, if you don't do this step you'll run into problems.
INSERT into @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'
--Select the JSON string from the Table we just inserted it into. You'll also be able to see the entire string with this statement.
SELECT * FROM @json

DESTROY: 

EXEC sp_OADestroy @token 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data type variable from 4000 to max was the first step.

The final blow was to comment out the following IF statement.
Maybe someone can enlighten me why this statement is not working as expected.

```
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;
--IF @ret <> 0 
    --BEGIN
    --    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object, @src OUT, @desc OUT
    --    SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @ret), 
    --        source = @src,
    --        description = @desc,
    --        FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed',
    --        MethodName = @methodName 
    --    goto destroy 
    --    return
    --END
```